# jQuery Find Closest Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have structure like each image has input below. I have x images on the screen. Each of image has onlick option

```
onclick="imageClicked(this)"
```

Function creates border to image and show collapsed input. Image`s border is showing but input is not beign visible.

Here`s the function

```
function imageClicked(image) {
    var input = $(image).closest("input");
    $(image).css('outline', "solid 2px #5bc0de");
    $(input).css("visibility", "visible");
    $(input).focus();

    $(input).focusout(function () {
        $(image).css('outline', "0");
        if ($(input).val() === "0") {
            $(input).css("visibility", "collapse");
        }
    });
    $(image).focusout(function () {
        if ($(input).val() === "") {
            $(image).css('outline', "0");
        }
    });
}
```

Here is HTML Structure in Razor View

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Boxes.Count; i++){
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Boxes[i].Photo);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);

    var imageId = Model.Boxes[i].BoxId;
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Boxes[i].BoxId)    
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="@imgSrc" width="50%" alt="@Model.Boxes[i].Name" id="@string.Format("image{0}", imageId)" onclick="imageClicked(this)" />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Boxes[i].Quantity, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "visibility: collapse; width: 50%; margin-top: 1%", @id = string.Format("input{0}", imageId) })
    </div>
}
```

Comment: need the html structure as well..

Comment: `$(image).closest("input");` but `closest()` is looking for ancestor and because an `input` is void element, it cannot have any descendant...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Closest will search for the parent elements. Here the input is not the parent element of the image. Its a sibling only. You can use siblings() selector for this purpose.

```
var input = $(image).siblings("input");
```

Or you can use,

```
var input = $(image).closest(".col-md-2").find("input");
```

- Get the parent div(since the image and input are under same parent)
- Then find the child input of that parent